# Pass string array as argument with function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, function-pointers

I'm trying to pass *a function pointer* to another *function*, which has a string array as arguments. so far I have the following:

```
void pass_function(string args[]) {    
    //so something with args.
}

void takes_a_function(void(*function)(string[])) {
    function;
}

int main()
{
    string s[] = { "hello", "World" };
    takes_a_function(pass_function(s));

    system("pause");    
    return 0;
}
```

the issue appears to be that that the parameter `pass_function(s)` is casting as a `void` rather than `void(*function)(sting *)`

I'm imagining it requires a cast but would prefer a cleaner was of doing it if possible.

Comment: `pass_function(s)` is of type `void` because you called the function. And then you tried to pass the return value.

Comment: your `takes_a_function` is noop

Comment: Could you describe what you are actually trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would prefer a cleaner was of doing it if possible.

From here

```
takes_a_function(pass_function(s));
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

it looks like you want to pass a something callable(`pass_function`) to another function(`takes_a_function`), after *binding* the argument(*string array*). If so, you have better options in C++.

First use either `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::array<std::string, 2>`(*if size is known*) to store the strings. Secondly, the passing of callable to another function, by either of the following ways:

1. **Using a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and
   [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)**

   Make `takes_a_function` as a template function and then after
   binding with the argument pass the callable object(`pass_function`
   as a lambda function) to it.

   ```
   #include <vector>     // std::vector
   #include <functional> // std::bind

   template<typename Callable> 
   void takes_a_function(const Callable &function) 
   {
       function(); // direckt call
   }

   int main()
   {
       std::vector<std::string> s{ "hello", "World" };
       auto pass_function = [](const std::vector<std::string> &args) { /*do something*/ };

       takes_a_function(std::bind(pass_function, s));        
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. **Using function pointer**

   If the function pointer is unavoidable, you need two arguments in
   `takes_a_function`, one should be the function pointer and the other
   should be the array of strings.

   ```
   #include <vector>     // std::vector

   // convenience type
   using fPtrType = void(*)(std::vector<std::string> const&);

   void pass_function(const std::vector<std::string> &args) { /*do something*/ };

   void takes_a_function(const fPtrType &function, const std::vector<std::string> &args)
   {
       function(args); // call with args
   }

   int main()
   {
       std::vector<std::string> s{ "hello", "World" };
       takes_a_function(pass_function, s);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
takes_a_function(pass_function);
```

Alternatively:

```
void pass_function(std::string args[]);

void takes_a_function(void(*function)(std::string[]), std::string args[]) {
    function(args);
}

int main() {
    std::string s[] = { "hello", "World" };
    takes_a_function(pass_function, s);
}
```